# Site - visualforce - inlineEditSupport

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, inlineeditsupport

i have a problem with site, where in a custom page i cant use the inlineEditSupport, while is possible when im logged in sfdc.

I checked the profile, which has access to  all files of interest.
the link to the page is:
http://bets-developer-edition.eu2.force.com/MyPage?id=001b000000Mhmgm

follows the code of the page:
`

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection >

        <apex:outputField value="{!Acc.Firstname__c}">

           <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="WelcomeSave, cancelButton"  />   

        </apex:outputField>

        <apex:outputField value="{!Acc.Lastname__c}">

           <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="WelcomeSave, cancelButton"  />   

        </apex:outputField>            

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

`
where Acc is an account.

Anyone can help me?

Thnk,
Klodjan

Comment: What is your error?  Are the buttons not showing, or do they not react to a change?

Comment: Actually it the fields don't react to a change. 
Sorry, my before link was wrong, i corrected it.

Comment: What does your "WelcomeSave" button do? does it call a custom save method? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: They are just declared as commandbutton buttons without any action.

I dont think that it depends by showOnEdit because the inline edit support work when im logged into the sandbox, but doesnt whe I interact with site.

I don't know if there is a different restriction for site, or I have forgot any configuration.

Comment: I didn't pick up on it being sites.  Is the site user authenticated?  Does that user profile and license type have permission to edit accounts.  Can the same profile edit an account without using the vf page? Are you sure the command button is the same in your sandbox?  What is you add a save action?

Comment: Hi, i found it, im just stupid :) 
to the site, which is public, is associated a gest licence which give just the permission to create and read the standard objects, and is not possible to add further permissions as edit,Delete, View All, Modify All. Differently for the custom objects is possible to give all the permissions that you want to the gest user. 

So for the gest user is not possible edit,delete, view all or modify all.

sorry, and thnks
Klodjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the site, which is public, is associated a gest licence which give just the permission to create and read the standard objects, and is not possible to add further permissions as edit,Delete, View All, Modify All. 
Differently for the custom objects is possible to give all the permissions that you want to the gest user. So for the gest user is not possible edit,delete, view all or modify all.

bye,
Klodjan